# How do I programmatically add a exit button to a UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiview

When I created a UIView in my superview, I want to add a button to this view that act as an exit button.
So when pressed, it will remove this UIView from my superview, how should I do that?
The View and button in that view is created programmatically when a button is pressed

```
- (IBAction)skillButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender 
{
    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 130, 240, 232)];
    UIButton *cancelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [cancelButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32)];
    [cancelButton setTitle:@"x" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [myView addSubview:cancelButton];
    [self.view addSubview:myView];
}
```

Comment: In that first of the which view controller u can present is it a navigation controller,UItabbar ..etc ?

Comment: It's created in the first viewController, something like a popup window on your screen, so the exit button will close this window

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your class that creates the view, add a function like this:

```
//tag for subview - make it unique
#define SUBVIEW_TAG 9999 

- (void) handleExit
{
    UIView * subview = [self.view viewWithTag:SUBVIEW_TAG];
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

and when creating the subview do:

```
- (IBAction)skillButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender 
{
    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 130, 240, 232)];
    UIButton *cancelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleExit) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cancelButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32)];
    [cancelButton setTitle:@"x" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [myView addSubview:cancelButton];
    [myView setTag:SUBVIEW_TAG];
    [self.view addSubview:myView];

    //don't forget to release if you are not using ARC!
}
```

Comment: do I need to create a separate method for that button? and use selector to call that method when I touch the button?

Comment: yes - if you are using InterfaceBuilder, then declare an **- (IBAction) handleExit;** function in your view's header file and connect the **Touch Up Inside** event of the button with the view.

Comment: Do you mind show me how to do it programatically? Cause the view and button are created programatically in my case

Comment: Sure - show me the code where you create the UIView that is the subview and where you add the button.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for you:

```
        self->myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    self-> myButton = CGRectMake(60, 6, 180, 30);
    [self-> myButton setTitle:@"MyButton" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self-> myButton setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    self-> myButton = 1;
    [self-> myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonTouchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:self-> myButton];
```

Change the coordinates for your button placing

In *myButtonTouchUpInside* method implemetation,

```
[self removeFromSuperview];
```

Hope this is what you want..

Comment: Yes, that is kind of what I'm looking for, do you mind show me how to implement myButtonTouchUpInside. I tried something like this but it doesn't work '- (IBAction)exitView:(UIView *)sender
{
    [sender removeFromSuperview];
}'

Comment: The sender is the button.  You should send `removeFromSuperview` to self, as three different people have already told you.

Comment: when i put [self removeFromSuperview]; in the method, compiler says: "receiver type 'myClassName' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'removeFromSuperview'." what's wrong with that? :(

Answer (score 1):

You can even hide the view or `[self removeFromSuperview];`